# MySQL Data to Highchart's Pie Chart using JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

I am Trying to create a HighCahrts JS's PIE CHART using The Data I fetched From the MySQL Data, Which I fetched into The JSON Format .

Here is my php Code :

```
foreach($row as $rec)  
{  
$json_array['label']=$rec['user_type_detail'];  
$json_array['value']=$rec['id']; 

array_push($json_data,$json_array);  
}  
?>
```

The JSON I am Getting is :

```
[{"label":"Government Doctor","value":"8"},
 {"label":"Private Doctor","value":"5"},
 {"label":"Public Doctor","value":"6"},
 {"label":"Student","value":"4"}
]
```

But THe problem is that Pie Chart is not being displayed on the Page. its just Blank.

I am USing the div with id="container"

And Here is my Script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie'
},
title: {
    text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
},
credits: {
  enabled: false
},
exporting: { enabled: false } ,
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
},
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
            style: {
                color: (Highcharts.theme && 
Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
            }
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Brands',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data:<?php echo json_encode($json_data) ?>
}]
});
</script>
```

Comment: Errors in developers console?

Comment: Funny Thing. There are no Errors.

Comment: And if you'll look into generated js code, what is there?

Comment: You mean this one

      series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data:[{"label":"Government Doctor","value":"8"},{"label":"Private 
    Doctor","value":"5"},{"label":"Public Doctor","value":"6"}, 
    {"label":"Student","value":"4"}]    }]
    });

Comment: data:  [{"label":"Government Doctor","value":"8"},{"label":"Private Doctor","value":"5"},{"label":"Public Doctor","value":"6"},{"label":"Student","value":"4"}]  @u_mulder

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the data format required by Highcharts:

```
    data: [{
            "name": "Government Doctor",
            "y": 8
        },
        {
            "name": "Private Doctor",
            "y": 5
        },
        {
            "name": "Public Doctor",
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "name": "Student",
            "y": 4
        }
    ]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ce72x3bu/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.data

Comment: this is static . How Can I bring the JSON Data which I mentioned above in this form ?

Comment: Hi @Abnit Chauhan, You can preprocess your data in JS: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1ru9qxs3/

Comment: the line under the series data: data is displaying as it is in my code. not fetching any data

Comment: @Abnit Chauhan, I am not a PHP expert, but why can not you use: `$json_array['name']=$rec['user_type_detail'];` instead of `$json_array['label']=$rec['user_type_detail'];`?